# CakeSession::write() Not working on remote server, but works fine on localhost

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this code which authenticate user for login and it works fine on localhost but on remote server does not work. It only loads and stays on the login page. But when username or password is wrong it gives the error message well.

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
            $data = $this->request->data;
           $password = sha1($data['password']);
            $email = $data['email'];

            $authUser = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.email' =>
            $email, 'User.password' => $password)));
            if(count($authUser) > 0){

                CakeSession::write('loggedInUser', $authUser['User']['id']);
                CakeSession::write('loggedInName', $authUser['User']['first_name'].' '.$authUser['User']['last_name']);
                CakeSession::write('verStatus', $authUser['User']['verified']);

                if(null != CakeSession::read('loggedInUser')){

                   $this->redirect('/shop');

                }

            }else{
               $loginError = 'Invalid username or password';
                $this->set('invalid', $loginError);
            }
        }
```

Can any one have an idea of what is happening?
My Cakephp version is 2.5.4

Comment: Why aren't you using the `Auth` and `Session` components? Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$this->Session->write('loggedInName',$authUser['User']['first_name'].' '.$authUser['User']['last_name']);
```

same for session->read .

Like this . And check PHP version at both sides.

Read   [**This**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html)

Also clear cache , temp folder  , switch core.php -> debug to 2 , then again to 0.

Comment: This is still doing the same thing. I've just tried it. I think the main thing here is that Session is not being set.

Comment: Somewhere along the line SESSIONS ARE UNSET Or DESTROYED in your code

Comment: My version is PHP 5.4

Comment: Somewhere along the line SESSIONS ARE UNSET Or DESTROYED in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Session->write('key','value');
```

I think above syntax must be used.

Comment: This is still doing the same thing. I've just tried it. I think the main thing here is that Session is not being set.

Answer (score 0):

That problem can be from file session storing permissions on dedicated server, for skip this issue you can save session in to database, please follow the link below and look at my answer (about configure session and create new table for it).
[Session Permission Denied on AWS after setting up Cake php.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813837/session-permission-denied-on-aws-after-setting-up-cake-php/21826337#21826337)
Hope it will be helpful for you.